# 64 bit vs 32 bit machine in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

We developed a application in VS2008 in 64-bit machine.We need to host into 32 bit server. Whether it will work in that Server?. Previously We face an issue, developed in 32 bit cant run in 64 bit server, it doesnt support some assembly, So for we build in 64 bit machine and we hosted in server.Is there any reason behind that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you application pool settings you need to enable 32-Bit Applications, then your application will work

This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/11/03/iis7-running-32-bit-and-64-bit-asp-net-versions-at-the-same-time-on-different-worker-processes.aspx) explains in more detail how to do this

Comment: Could you please explain more?